# How to create a relationship for single start node and multiple end node using spring boot and Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j, graph-databases, neo4j-ogm

I have scenario for user/role mapping to do CRUD operations. For that in Neo4j I have
the following nodes

1. User
2. Role
3. Blueprint
4. Template
5. Catalogue

I could make a relationship with user for appropriate role. Now, I need to create a relationship between start node for Role and the end node 
for Blueprint, Template and Catalogue and I'm using spring boot with GraphRepository.

Could anyone please help me to know about this and thoughts would be appreciated ?

TIA..,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many resources available that will help you create relationships using Spring Data Neo4j-

The reference documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RC2/reference/html/

Article: http://www.airpair.com/neo4j/posts/the-essence-of-spring-data-neo4j-4

Example projects: http://github.com/neo4j-examples?query=sdn4

If you run into specific issues, please post a question with sufficient context and what you tried so we can help you better.